# Is there ways to download youtube video?

Tags: 13.04, software-recommendation, youtube

[Youtube](http://youtube.com) is my 3nd favorite web after [Google](http://google.com) and [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com), everyday i always watch new video from Youtube, but I do not like about YouTube is video buffering,  so annoying to wait it. Now my question is there ways/program to install YouTube Videos quickly and user friendly ?

**UPDATE**

I know there's many ways to download YouTube videos using terminal, add-ons and other but any is there anyone here who can explain it in detail and use simple words ?

Comment: Just pick up a higher vote answer with simple simple steps, try it. Does not look the one you want try next one.

Answer (score 1):

Use an online youtube downloader, such as [this](http://ytconv.net/)

Just select the output format you'd like.

Comment: It's work ! But any method to install youtube video ?

Answer (score 0):

Install [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and the you can use this Addon:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1-click-youtube-video-downl/